# Python - Combine two lists - Title and Data

Tags: python, list, sqlite, iterable

I'm working with SQLite.

I have two lists. `res1` which holds the title of my sql query results, which consists of only two values (/ columns of the final list) and `res2` which is the list that holds the data (two dimensional).

How can i assign `res` list to `res1` and then append / extend / insert `res2` list right after so that it looks like this.

```
|Column1  | Column2|
|row1Val1 | row1Va2|
|row2Val1 | row2Va2|
|row3Val1 | row3Va2|
|row4Val1 | row4Va2|
```

etc..

I have tried, insert at specific index, extend and others. They don't work. How can i do that without for / loop iteration? There must be such a function, or a way to do something so simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either I do not understand what you ask for or the answer is very simple:

```
res = [res1] + res2
```